# Migration from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to migrate database from SQL Server 2000 Enterprise edition to SQL Server R2 Standard edition?

I read some where that you can upgrade SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, but you can’t upgrade SQL Server 2000 Enterprise to SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard. But I want to migrate database from SQL Server 2000 Enterprise edition to SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition, so is it possible?

Comment: As long as you haven't used any Enterprise-only features in your database, I don't see any problems with upgrading .....

Comment: Currently SQL 2000 enterprise edition is installed in XP machine. But Sql 2008 R2 is installed in Windows 7 machine. The database which is present in windwos xp machine having the size of nearly 11GB. I am taking the back up for that file and restoring in windows 7 machine.

Comment: Processed 48600 pages for database 'MY_DB', file 'MY_DB' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'MY_DB', file 'MY_DB_log' on file 1.
Converting database 'MY_DB' from version 539 to the current version 661.
Database 'MY_DB' running the upgrade step from version 539 to version 551.
Database 'MY_DB' running the upgrade step from version 539 to version 661.
Database 'MY_DB' running the upgrade step from version 539 to version 551.
Msg 3167, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE could not start database 'MY_DB'.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Have you tried [using MS Upgrade Advisor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256(v=sql.105).aspx) to check for any potential upgrade problems?

Comment: till now i didnt checked this. In which sql server i need to check this?(Sql 2000 or Sql 2008 R2)

Comment: **READ that article I linked to!** It spells out clearly how and where to install the upgrade advisor, and how to run it....